# The activity generated by flutter could not be found

Tags: android, flutter

The stack is as follows：

```
2019-03-21 14:23:50.883 10148-10148/com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter, PID: 10148
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter/com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter.activity.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter-HTuMLA_86hLW95aeKW4w3g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter-HTuMLA_86hLW95aeKW4w3g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter-HTuMLA_86hLW95aeKW4w3g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2847)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3033)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6811)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:817)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter.activity.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter-HTuMLA_86hLW95aeKW4w3g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter-HTuMLA_86hLW95aeKW4w3g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.qiangxi.wx_assistant_flutter-HTuMLA_86hLW95aeKW4w3g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2837)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3033) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6811) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:817)
```

I looked at the dex file and didn't find the Activity class.
But actually this activity is there，

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    companion object {
        private val EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

        MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL_APK_INFO)
            .setMethodCallHandler { methodCall, result ->
                val method = methodCall.method
                when (method) {
                    METHOD_GET_APK_INFO -> {
                        EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit {
                            val apks = ApkModel.obtainAndParseApk(applicationContext)
                            if (apks.isEmpty()) {
                                result.error("error", "no result.", null)
                            } else {
                                result.success(apks)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and manifest file:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.qiangxi.wx.assistant.flutter">

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="wx_assistant_flutter"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and build.gradle ：

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.qiangxi.wx.assistant.flutter"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I have checked the relevant code, did not find any problems, I do not understand why there is no Activity class in the dex file, please tell me why, thanks!

[the picture -> dex file has no Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb7f2.png)

[image]

Comment: have you tried removing the app completely i.e cleaning its caches and then installing it again?

Comment: I have uninstalled the apk, the cache has been deleted, and it has been reinstalled, but the problem is still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, because I manually modified the project to the kotlin language, but did not add kotlin related dependencies, resulting in kotlin related classes not compiled, so there is no kotlin related class in the generated apk.

Comment: What are the kotlin related dependencies you're talking about here ?